# Confusion with hiding some input fields using JS vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox, field

I want to show hidden input fields when check "Buy on company" checkbox. It works, but if I uncheck it leaving "Is VAT exemt" checked and return: "VAT ID field" is shown with "Is VAT exemt" checkbox checked. So I want to avoid this situation.

Picture of situation:

[image]

```js
document.getElementById('billing_company').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('billing_company_code').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt_field').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';

document.getElementById('buy_on_company').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('billing_company').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('billing_company_code').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt_field').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billing_company').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('billing_company_code').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt_field').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';
  }
};

document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'block';
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="buy_on_company_field">
  <input type="checkbox" id="buy_on_company"><label>Buy on company</label>
</div>

<div id="billing_company_field">
  <input type="text" id="billing_company" placeholder="Company name" style="display: block;">
</div>

<div id="billing_company_code_field">
  <input type="text" id="billing_company_code" placeholder="Company code" style="display: block;">
</div>

<div id="is_vat_exempt_field">
  <input type="checkbox" id="is_vat_exempt"><label>Is VAT exempt</label>
</div>

<div id="billing_vat_id_field">
  <input type="text" id="billing_vat_id" placeholder="VAT ID field" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

Comment: The code for clicking on `Buy on company` needs to test the VAT checkbox to decide whether to show the VAT input.

Comment: document.getElementById is quite a heavy operation, you only need to do it once then you can reuse the cached variables, also learning how to select and traverse the dom could reduce your code to like 7 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for clicking on `buy_on_company` is always hiding or showing the `billing_vat_id` field. It needs to test that checkbox.

```js
document.getElementById('billing_company').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('billing_company_code').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt_field').style['display'] = 'none';
document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';

document.getElementById('buy_on_company').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('billing_company').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('billing_company_code').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt_field').style['display'] = 'block';
    if (document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').checked) {
      document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'block';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billing_company').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('billing_company_code').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt_field').style['display'] = 'none';
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';
  }

};

document.getElementById('is_vat_exempt').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'block';
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="buy_on_company_field">
  <input type="checkbox" id="buy_on_company"><label>Buy on company</label>
</div>

<div id="billing_company_field">
  <input type="text" id="billing_company" placeholder="Company name" style="display: block;">
</div>

<div id="billing_company_code_field">
  <input type="text" id="billing_company_code" placeholder="Company code" style="display: block;">
</div>

<div id="is_vat_exempt_field">
  <input type="checkbox" id="is_vat_exempt"><label>Is VAT exempt</label>
</div>

<div id="billing_vat_id_field">
  <input type="text" id="billing_vat_id" placeholder="VAT ID field" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But vat id field is left, when uncheck "Buy on conpany"

Comment: Fixed. I moved that test inside the `if` block that displays all the other fields.

Comment: Hmm. Is it just for me? Vat ID field is left the same, then uncheck everything.

Comment: This just hides and shows, it doesn't change the contents of anything.

Comment: Yes, but I still get https://i.imgur.com/46Y0cmt.png

Comment: Now I fixed that in my last answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One line was missing, to hide "billing_vat_id" in second 'else' statement.

```
document.getElementById('billing_vat_id').style['display'] = 'none';
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJg1a.png

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the problem was and how you solved it.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar.